# I want to display the collections data on the front end UI and which is already stored in the mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Connecting mongoDB with reactJS without using Nodejs

I am expecting some lines of code related to connection between mongoDB and ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

Just make a db.js file

```
 import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(<YOUR_MONGO_URI>, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    })

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

export default connectDB
```

Just import this file to your main server file and call the exported function

Comment: Without using any backend